# java on linux - hide ssl.keyStorePassword

Tags: java, linux, security, ssl, passwords

How can I hide keyStorePassword and trustStorePassword from below ps listing?

```
ec2-user   6348      1  6 06:49 ?        00:26:56 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx8048m -Djava_net_preferIPv4Stack=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5 -Dhadoop.id.str=ec2-user -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx512m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /usr/lib/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-metastore-2.3.2.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore

ec2-user  17784      1 10 06:58 ?        00:44:00 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx8048m -Djava_net_preferIPv4Stack=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5 -Dhadoop.id.str=ec2-user -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.5/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx512m -Dproc_hiveserver2 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=hive-log4j2.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/lib/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/conf/parquet-logging.properties -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /usr/lib/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-service-2.3.2.jar org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console

ec2-user  18710   6049 19 06:59 ?        01:21:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -cp /home/ec2-user/spark_home/conf/:/home/ec2-user/spark_home/jars/* -Xmx58368M -Dspark.ssl.enabledAlgorithms=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 -Dspark.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Dspark.ssl.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Dspark.network.timeout=7200s -Dspark.ssl.enabled=true -Dspark.ssl.trustStore=/home/ec2-user/spark_home/conf/alias-trust-nonprd.jks -Dspark.port.maxRetries=1600 -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.port=3128 -Dspark.rpc.numRetries=1600 -Dspark.rpc.lookupTimeout=7200s -Dspark.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2 -Dspark.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=700 -Dspark.ssl.keyPassword=changeit -Dspark.blockManager.port=38000 -Dspark.driver.port=38002 -Dspark.ssl.keyStore=/home/ec2-user/spark_home/conf/alias-nonprd.jks org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ip-iphere.domain:38002 --executor-id 0 --hostname ip --cores 48 --app-id app-20180524065933-0000 --worker-url spark://Worker@ip:33239
```

Comment: Don't provide passwords as command-line arguments. Instead use an environment variable and load it programmatically.

Comment: Can hive and spark components do that ? I am just calling bin/hive and spark/start-slave.sh

Comment: why downvoted ?

Comment: @tooptoop4 Maybe the question is downvoted because we don't know what efforts you made to solve the problem by yourself (what you tried before asking). This is typical of "how can I" and "why not working" questions. It's not always easy to show efforts, and ironically some very easy questions get thousands of upvotes because their answer is useful to the community. Although we never know who votes, we can see a user's +/- votes statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*trustStorePassword* is not as important as *keyStorePassword* and you might choose different solutions for both. As suggested in the comment, *keyStorePassword* should be read from a "protected" (readable by its owner only) property file, this is what we find in the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#GUID-A41282C3-19A3-400A-A40F-86F4DA22ABA9__SYSTEMPROPERTIESANDCUSTOMIZEITEMSIN-DCEEB591).